# IEEE 754 conversion

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

I'm trying to convert 3.2 into IEEE 754 format. We find that $(3)_2=11$ and we also find that

$0.2*2=0.4 -0$

$0.4*2=0.8 -0$

$0.8*2=1.6 -1$

$0.6*2=1.2 -1$

and this cycle repeats so $.2=00110011...$

finally we find $11.00110011...$

we normalize $1.1001001...*2^{1}$
and calculate the exponent $127+1=128=10000000$

we find that the IEEE 754 conversion is
010000000 10011001100110011001100

but all online converters give a one in the last place, or, to put it as an example, it looks like this

010000000 10011001100110011001101

Why is this so? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please add a bit about *IEEE 754 rounding*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rounded down, but the online converters rounded to nearest.

Think of it this way: the "real" mantissa would be $\frac{8}{5}$. You subtracted the implicit one to get $\frac{3}{5}$, then multiplied by $2^{23}$ to get the significand field plus an "error" term:

$$\frac{67108864}{5} = 13421772 + \frac{4}{5}$$

You can see that $13421772$ in decimal is $10011001100110011001100$ in binary, but that error term is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, so it should be rounded up.

Of course, that's not how IEEE-754 rounding is done in practice.

Comment: This really helps. Ty

Comment: Im an idiot. In retrospect this is so obvious I can't believe it.